# Recursive search with Lua objects

Tags: recursion, lua, pseudocode

In Lua, I have a tree relationship structure between objects where an object can have multiple children, but only one parent object, i.e.

obj---obj1---obj2---objd3---obj4---obj5---obj6

If I want to know obj6's 'distant' parents instead of just the immediate parent obj5, how can I achieve that? I just need a list of parents two or more levels above the current object, and the API I'm working with only has a obj.parent property.

Pseudo-code would also be helpful to get me in the right direction.

Comment: What have you tried? You seem to know that you have to do a recursive search, so, well, do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if your api supports `.parent`, can't you do something like the following? I'm rusty with Lua but this should offer a start.

```
local function GetAncestors(child)

    local ancestors = {};

    if child.parent then
        local i = 0;
        ancestors[0] = child.parent;
        while ancestors[i].parent do
            ancestors[i + 1] = ancestors[i].parent;
            i = i + 1;
        end
    end

    return ancestors;

end
```

Comment: Thanks so much this was exactly what I was trying to do. :)

Comment: Btw, this should get you the requested `list of parents` from which you may then exclude whichever generations you'd like. Like I said, if I have some logic/syntax issue here let me know.

Answer (score 3):

```
obj.parent               -- immediate parent (obj5)
obj.parent.parent        -- parent's parent (obj4)
obj.parent.parent.parent -- parent's parent's parent (obj3)
```

So on and so forth?

If you want to avoid trying to referencing a non-existent parent, I supposed you could do something like:

```
function getAncestor(obj, depth)
   if not obj.parent then
      return nil
   elseif depth > 1 then
      return getAncestor(obj.parent, depth-1)
   end
   return obj.parent
end


-- get parent
obj = getAncestor(obj6)

-- get great great grandparent
obj = getAncestor(obj6, 3)
```